# How to get all items which are not part of a GSI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Imagine you have a dynamodb table with following properties (all strings):

- `userId` <- hash key
- `companyId`
- `firstname`
- etc..

In this case it can be possible that the user has no `companyId` so it can be empty/non-existent for some db entries.

Now you create a global secondary index (GSI) with the `companyId` as hash key.

**Question**

Is it possible  to query all db entries that have *no* `companyId` by using the GSI above? If no, what other options (without a `scan`) are there?

**Considered option**

Technically you could set all `companyId`'s to a value like `"empty"` but in my opinion that leads to a not so inutuitive coding experience since you would need to check `companyId == "empty"` instead of `companyId == null` (which is the usual and known way to check for empty variables).

Comment: There is no *efficient* way to select all items that don't exist in a GSI.  Perhaps you could index on an attribute `employment_status` and set it to EMPLOYED or UNEMPLOYED.  The details of a better way will depend entirely on the access patterns you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found, GSIs don’t index null values. In fact, as it turns out, that is a super useful feature because it allows for very efficient indexes when the index is sparse (indexed key is not present on most items in the table).

In your case, the most optimal solution depends on the density of items that have no companyId. If most don’t have one, a scan will be your best friend. If, on the other had, most items do have a companyId then you could create either an “empty” value or create another attribute (ie hasNoCompany) and index on that.

Finally, you should consider why you need “all items” with no company: again, if there are lots of such items a scan might still be more appropriate.

Comment: A scan will look at all rows of the table, regardless of the values in the rows. You should not use a scan when looking for particular rows unless the number of rows in the table is small.

Comment: Size of the table is not the important metric. It is the density of the items your are looking for: if you expect most items in the table to match what you are looking for then scan is the way to go.

Comment: My apologies; I read your statement backward. I thought you were saying that if there aren't a lot of records matching the search criteria then scan was the way to go. You are saying scan is good if there ARE a lot of records matching the criteria.